# White paste and strong plastic smell on induction stove

Tags: induction, paste

My induction hob, when in use for several minutes on high heat is producing a very heavy plastic smell. The hob is working properly besides this smell.

I opened the back of the hob and noticed this white paste that melted, it seems that this is what is causing the smell - what can it be?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check wires, smell may come from burned insulation.

Comment: I added another pictures, wires were all fine

Comment: Device can not be used without pot or something else on working surface. And it should be ferromagnetic. Overview it is overheating. Normally stove has overheating protection.

Comment: There was a pot otherwise it can’t start

Comment: Feeder wires looks stranger. If it is strong smell must be burned plastic, visible. Take a look more places.

Comment: There are independent power circuits for each coil.  Was it for any HOB?  There are no symptoms of heatstress in photo.  I assume fan was running.

Comment: That’s a great point, I will try each hob one by one and see if it is localized to a specific one. The fan was running. Thanks!

Comment: If it's brand new it MAY be normal and go away in a few days. But as Tony suggests, run each hob (boil a pan of water) in turn and see if they are all the same.

Comment: epoxy and PVC fumes are toxic, so limit exposure

Comment: The white thermal paste is not the issue. It has not melted.

Comment: With respect, if you are unaware that thermal paste is a thing, you are clearly not qualified to be poking around in this thing.  That's E-tech 101 stuff.   You don't know what you're looking at and you can seriously get hurt, or worse you get somebody else hurt (i.e. if a fire occurs).  Even if you find the 'bad part', you're not in a position to know it's really a 'bad part', or if something else failed which in turn caused the part in question to overheat.   (That's a very common scenario in electronics).   Strongly suggest you send this to the manufacturer for repair or just get a new one.

Comment: please, carefully examine the power cord at both ends

Answer (score 4):

The white paste is normal.  It's heatsink compound that is used to help the transfer of heat from that active semiconductor device to the large heat sink.

As far as your smell?  It's not possible to tell from the information given.

Now it is possible that the device itself it getting too hot and since it's encased in plastic, that might be your cause.

Comment: The smell is intense, I had to open all windows for an hour to get rid of it, smell like plastic, I added one more picture

Comment: Clearly there is something wrong.  A burning smell is not normal.

Comment: Is that expected for this white paste to be liquid?

Comment: @No, white paste should not be liquid. It is silicone based.

Comment: Ok that’s an indicator, I could remove it (it was a tiny bit sticky)

Comment: Outside you can. Important has it between transistor and heatsink. But that stuff does not burn.

Comment: The white paste actually can be a paste or grease which is really just a very viscous liquid. I still believe the white paste is normal. The problem is elsewhere. If something is that hot it may be possible to detect it by holding your hand close to it and feeling the heat come off of it. Of course if you touch something you may also get a shock or even get electrocuted. So maybe you don't want to do that. Your risk and your decision. But you have to find the source of the heat or call a competent technician to fix it.

Comment: If you have a non-contact thermometer it may help pinpoint the hot spot.

Comment: Note non-contact thermometers "see" heat reflections also - careful you're measuring an actual temperature and not whatever's reflected off a shiny surface.

Comment: @John Sticky is fine, runny is not fine, since it's sticky and not runny it's perfectly normal. I don't know why you are focused on this white paste. The paste is supposed to be there